# Alternative tools for servicing a Fox fork 2016+

Tags: fork, tools, fox

Official tools are too expensive. I mean lower leg removal, seal driver and seal extractor tools. Forks with new seals from 2016 onwards. Which alternative tools do you use?

My fork: 2017 Fox 32 Float SC Performance 29", 100mm Travel, FIT4 Damper, Remote Lockout, Boost 15x110 KaBolt, Tapered.

UPDATE: Pictures of seal driver and lower leg removal tool. Taken from [here](http://bicimaxstore.com/).

[image: fox seal driver]
[image: leg removal tool]

Comment: If you have access to a 3D printer, The 3D models for seal drivers are freely available on the internet.

Comment: @mattnz: good point, unfortunately I don't have 3d printer.

Comment: @PatricioMontes, did you end up buying the tool to remove the lowers or did you use the suggestion from the answer below?

Comment: @Squashman, I didn't. I do as the answer explains, and even better I use a [piece of wood](https://youtu.be/tlJF1vtIsds?t=174). Some pictures [here](https://www.foromtb.com/threads/brico-mantenimiento-fox-32-cambio-retenes-y-aceite.305224/page-168#post-27037093).

Comment: @PatricioMontes, that is brilliant.  Not sure why I didn't think of using a dowel. My uncle has a full woodshop, I could have had him drill me one out.  I ended up ordering the tool because I found it fairly cheap online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to service your own fork occasionally, you don't need to buy specialized tools.

To remove the seals you can use an large wrench/spanner, be careful not to scratch the inside of the tubes:

[Images are taken from this guide](https://www.bike-magazin.de/service/schrauber_tipps/federgabel-service-fuer-fox-gabeln/a30779.html)
[image]

Inserting the new seals can be done with a socket of the right size:

[image]

You don't need any special tools to remove the lower legs. Unthread the bottom nuts half way, then place the socket over them. Now you can gently tap the socket with a rubber mallet to loosen the lower legs, without hitting the rebound adjuster.

Comment: Welcome to SE - excellent answer.   Its generally a good idea to credit the source of your images.

Comment: @airace3: Fox has a special tool for removing lower legs, picture uploaded in question post. What do you do instead of using this tool? Thank you!

Comment: @PatricioMontes just edited the answer to explain it.

Comment: One more question. Pictures show an old seal, prior to 2016, newer ones are harder to insert. Do you still recommend a socket? Thanks.

Comment: @PatricioMontes Sorry, i don't have experience with the new dust wipers. After some searching in different forums it seems as if they are indeed much harder to insert. I would recommend to get the tool.

Comment: @airace3 Thank you. You are right, I have edited title and post to point it out.

Comment: The old style seals are still available if you shop around- often advertised as a better choice for the home mechanic.

Comment: @airace3 for removing the lowers that seems easier said then done with a StepCast fork.  Do you think that is feasible instead of using the tool (part no 398-00-682 A)???